# Internet Explorer Returns Error:404 upon loading a PHP webpage?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, http-status-code-404

My website has a login page which is in the PHP format, it includes HTML code below the PHP code to display the webpage, This works fine in Chrome or Firefox, but in IE I get the error:

> The webpage cannot be found

What is happening? Before this started, IE displayed the webpage with bad formatting.

Comment: Most likely some bad javascript code. Do you have any javascript in it ?

Comment: Maybe your behind a firewall and IE is blocked by the firewall? Or maybe you have set some proxy settings in IE?

Comment: There is some Jquery, but it works fine in other browsers. Also, what extra input do you want?

Comment: Show the code, or results in the developer console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the page quite small, with not much content?

When you view source in Internet Explorer, do you see the actual page content?

It's quite possible that the page is returning a 404 Not Found header. In that case, if the page content is small, Internet Explorer will show its own error message, instead of the page content. Firefox and other browsers will show the page content even if there are error messages. So will IE if the page content is large (I can't remember the actual number of bytes required).

I would suggest you use the Live HTTP Headers plugin for Firefox, or some other means to investigate the actual HTTP Headers returned by your script.